# FileZilla file uploading issue - Can't set permission to 777 for folder

Tags: file-upload, file-permissions, filezilla

When I **"set permission to 777"** it gives this error due to this I can't upload my file.

Please can any body help me to get rid of this issue. When I upload my file Critical file transfer error appears

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your second screenshot, you actually did not change permissions on the directory. The server rejected the change.

On *nix servers, you need to be an owner of a file/directory to be allowed to change its permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Your sever returns FTP 550 error, permission denied.  The problem is not with Filezilla. The user you logged on as does not have permission.

Comment: I am working on jumla site when i upload extention on to this site i have this issue only for specific extention